# List Report custom action in extension not displayed

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have created a Custom Action to a List Report FE through an extension.  The whole purpose is to export the data to a spreadsheet.  While testing it from VS Code, all the added extensions do work.  But after the app is deployed, none work.
FES is running SAPUI5 version 1.52.18 (S/4HANA 1709), in case you wonder.
Can't figure out if this is an error with the installation or in the extension I created.

Please find the code below:
Manifest:

```
            "extensions": {
            "sap.ui.viewExtensions": {
                "sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.view.ListReport": {}
            },
            "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
                "sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.view.ListReport": {
                    "controllerName": "com.sap.inventoryvariance.ext.controller.ListReportExt",
                    "sap.ui.generic.app": {
                        "ZGM_INV_VAR": {
                            "EntitySet": "ZGM_INV_VAR",
                            "Actions": {
                                "onExport": {
                                    "id": "ExportBtn",
                                    "text": "Export",
                                    "press": "onExport",
                                    "requiresSelection": false    
                                }
```

Extension:

```
sap.ui.controller("com.sap.inventoryvariance.ext.controller.ListReportExt", {
onExport : function(oEvent) { 
    alert('ExportToExcel');
}
```

});

I even tried using the setting "useExportToExcel": true.  While testing from VS Code, both work (but VS Code lowest SAPUI5 version is 1.65):

[image]

But from the deployed app, nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: Hey Tincho, do you mean [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/23/new-excel-export-functionality-available/) by `useExportToExcel` ? And are you using Gruntfile.js/build process in your Project ?

Comment: Hi MrNajzs.  Yes, exactly that functionality.  Tried both ways, none work.  As for the build, there is no gruntfile in project.  I leave npm to rule all about it.  But the app is deploy perfectly in backend.

Comment: I had the same problem with SAP WebIDE. In the WebIDE it worked perfectly fine. On the FES not... The SAP WebIDE didn't deploy the *propertyChanges* correctly. [Check if your propertyChanges even made it to the FES via SUI_SUPPORT](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/12/16/adaptation-project-get-to-know-how-to-extend-a-fiori-elements-app/#:~:text=The%20application%20would%20be%20saved%20in%20the%20Layered%20repository.%20It%20can%20be%20opened%20using%20transaction%20SUI_SUPPORT.)  After deactivating the build process the *propertyChanges* made it to the FES and everything worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I am doing a manual deploy through program /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD.  In SE80 I see all relevant files, but in SUI_SUPPORT only 3 (the ext folder is not there)

Comment: I am referring to the adaptation *useExportToExcel*. The change should be visible in a folder called "changes". Inside there are 1..n ".change" files. When building the App the system didn't recognize the ".change" file cause the build process changed it to *changes-bundle.json*. You can check it via SUI_SUPPORT(previous comment - this only shows the adaptions not the whole app like in se80(bsp)). After disabling the build process and deploying the app, the system recognized the changes and displayed them. - Im not talking about the ext folder. this worked fine for me with building process.

Comment: Checked SUI_SUPPORT and indeed there is no changes folder.  Checked the logs in SLG1 (obj /UI2/LREP) and can't see any errors there, so I assume app uploading worked fine.  Checked the manifest in LREP and do has the useExportToExcel = true, so this should be working already.  And controller file is not there in the app folder structure which would explain why the added custom action is not present.  So far I've been investigating this, did not find problem nor solution but clearly you nailed it on the issue